# List of tables that a user has SELECT privilege for in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-permissions

**Short version**: How can I write an SQL procedure to list which of several tables in a MySQL database a particular user has access to?

**Longer version**:

I'm writing a multi-user app that accesses a database with data for several branches of a company. The database has a number of lookup tables that any user can access, and a table for each branch that only authorized users can access. My strategy is:

- Write a stored procecure that returns a list of the relevant tables for which the user has SELECT privilege.
- From the app, call the procedure. If there's only one table returned, use it, otherwise let the user select which branch they want to access (e.g. for managers).

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write such a stored procedure. `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER` is an obvious possibility, but parsing something like:

```
GRANT SELECT ON Company.BranchABC TO 'auser'@'%clientdomain.com'
```

in SQL to figure out what the tables are seems *way* too messy. Doing a `SELECT` from the actual tables that hold the permissions also seems problematic, because I'd have to duplicate MySQL's logic for combining the permissions from the various tables (user, db, host, etc.)

Any words of wisdom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never granted per table permissions to MySQL users before, but to do this, you would check that the `TABLE_PRIVILEGES` table in the `information_schema` database.

That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: That works except they may have the select privilege at the `SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES` level or at the `USER_PRIVILEGES` level, so you need to check all.

Answer (score 7):

You can see what privileges on which tables a user has:

```
show grants for 'user'@'host';
```

For example, to see the privileges of user1 (all machines in the network 10.25), run:

```
show grants for 'user'@'10.25.%.%';
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL users list and its privilege can be check with the Query.

```
select * from mysql.user\G;
```

http://www.devdescent.com/2012/04/retrieve-mysql-users-list-and-its.html